# Conditional logic in Thank You letters

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, contributions

I recently took over the donor thank you letter process at the organization I work for and saw that Civi has the ability to create thank you letters for donors.

The organization I work for has 5 separate funds that members can contribute to. We want to be able to be able to send an automated thank you letter to contributors that reflects all of their contributions.

Is there a way to add an "if...then" sort of logic to these letters?

For instance:

- Member One donates $10 to Fund A
- Member Two donates $10 each to Fund
  B, C, and D
- Member Three donates $10 each to Fund B and E

We want to be able to automate letters that would say:

- Dear Member One, thank you for contributing $10 to Fund A.
- Dear Member Two, thank you for contributing $10 to Fund B, $10 to Fund C, and $10 to Fund D.
- and so on

I see tokens that auto populate for name, date, and address, but not for our individual funds themselves. I also don't see a way of specifying most recent contribution -- only total all-time or total last year.

Are there tokens I can use that will automatically pull from a member's contributions? Something like:

> Dear {firstname}, Thanks for donating {Fund A donation amount} to {Fund A}.

Or is this functionality not possible on Civi?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIR there is no such thing in Civi. I would have a look at available extensions extending tokens and if nothing covers your needs, write your own. This is not too heavy and a good starting point is the docs https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#custom combined with any token providing module source on github.

Answer (score 4):

[Civitoken](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) extensions provides additional tokens for contact. It would be worth trying the extension.

[image]

There are also few others

- [Contributions Table token](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contributions-table-token)
- [Payment Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/payment-tokens)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each contribution is separate, you can use the [Thank you letters with grouped contribution](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/#grouped-contribution-thank-you-letters) functionality to do what you want.  I find the formatting a little funky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CiviRules to send out thank you letters. You could then trigger on contribution added and then set the conditions (such as amount between xx and yy, and status is completed, and financial type is z, etc).

Use the Send e-mail action (provided by the email api extension) for sending the actual thank you e-mail.

You have to create a message template for each type of thank you letter, and a civirule for each type of thank you.